# How can I create virtual machine accessible on local network through web browser?

Tags: virtual-machines, local-area-network, proxmox

I would like to create vm (graphical and not graphical) on an existing ubuntu laptop, and I would like to access this VM through the local network (web browser for example)

This is something like proxmox, but proxmox is an OS, and *I don't want to install a new OS* (I would like this on the same pc that runs my ubuntu), I would prefer like a proxmox .deb package but it doesn't exist. Or may be convert proxmox to a docker image, and run proxmox in a docker container...?

Can someone help me?

thanks

Comment: Proxmox .deb package **does** exist: https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Install_Proxmox_VE_on_Debian_11_Bullseye

Comment: yes, only for debian OS, so i could install it on ubuntu but I'll have some issues...

Comment: Why didn't you just use libvirt and virt-manager?

Comment: yeah thanks for your answer, I already saw that, but I'am a very beginner in virtualization, but anyway I will inquire

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions might be running it in qemu as you wish (libvirt, etc.), with vnc screen enabled. And install a noVNC to access this vnc screen via browser. This is what Proxmox essentially does.

Comment: ok why not, thanks, i'm a beginner to virtualization, i'll inquire